# Reactjs: how to write unit test of method which has parameter as event

Tags: reactjs

```
changeCoverType(event){
    let coverSelection = event.target.value;

    let selectedCover = common[coverSelection]


    this.setState({

        activeCoverColor: selectedCover,

    });
}
```

I am writing a unit test for this method but I don't know what to pass in parameter. Someone please help me to write the unit test for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an object with the target and value as a property like this:

```
changeCoverType({ target: { value: 'covername' } })
```